# Retrieve serialize value in the database wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, serialization

I'm trying to query a serialized array value in the database in wordpress, value will be stored in the table wp_postmeta, in the column meta_value. 
Well, first I stored the array by using serialize() function of php. 
So for example,

```
$postID = 1;
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
$ser_val = serialize($arr);
update_meta_data($postID, '_customvalue', $ser_val);
```

The stored values is something like this

```
s:30:"a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;}";
```

Then when I tried to retrieve it by performing wordpress sql query.. What I was expecting that it will be an array since it is stored as array, but after doing so, it display as string not an array.

```
    $get_score = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_cummulativescore'");
    $scr = unserialize($get_score->meta_value);
    var_dump($scr);

    //output displayed
    //string(30) "a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;}"
```

I did check the value using is_array() function, the result is that it is not an array 
Any idea on this to get the serialize value as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data was converted to a string during serialization.

The data should be stored as

```
a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;}
```

instead of

```
s:30:"a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;}"
```

s:30 means string length 30.

Comment: So what would you suggest? should I perform a loop in storing the serialized array or not?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. I think your code is somehow performing the serialize on the array twice. Check if update_meta_data function may already be serializing, so you may skip your own serialize.

Comment: Hey, you are right. It is performing twice serialize. Now that should fix it. Thanks